# python 3.7 and quickfix on windows

Tags: c++, python-3.x, swig, quickfix

I'm on windows 10/64bit and I am just trying to test QuickFix with Python3 on Windows.
 I've installed Python 3.7.9 and QuickFix using quickfix‑1.15.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix)
pip install "c:\downloads\quickfix-1.15.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"

my client is derived from the examples (see at the end). As soon as I run:

```
acceptor = fix.SocketAcceptor( application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory )
```

i get the following error:

```
(env) C:\git\py\quickfix>py test0.py test_fix_client.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test0.py", line 39, in <module>
    acceptor = fix.SocketAcceptor( myApplication(), fix.FileStoreFactory(settings), fix.SessionSettings(fileName), fix.FileLogFactory(settings) )
  File "C:\git\py\quickfix\env\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 40014, in __init__
    SocketAcceptorBase.__init__(self, application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
  File "C:\git\py\quickfix\env\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 39817, in __init__
    this = _quickfix.new_SocketAcceptorBase(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_SocketAcceptorBase'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    FIX::SocketAcceptor::SocketAcceptor(FIX::Application &,FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,FIX::SessionSettings const &)
    FIX::SocketAcceptor::SocketAcceptor(FIX::Application &,FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,FIX::SessionSettings const &,FIX::LogFactory &)
```

what am i missing here? the parameters and signature seem ok.
Thanks!
Richard

```
>>> type(settings)
<class 'quickfix.SessionSettings'>
>>> type(application)
<class '__main__.myApplication'>
>>> type(logFactory)
<class 'quickfix.FileLogFactory'>
>>> type(storeFactory)
<class 'quickfix.FileStoreFactory'>

>>> help(fix.SocketAcceptor)
Help on class SocketAcceptor in module quickfix:

class SocketAcceptor(SocketAcceptorBase)
 |  SocketAcceptor(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory=None)
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      SocketAcceptor
 |      SocketAcceptorBase
 |      Acceptor
 |      builtins.object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __init__(self, application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory=None)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
```

...

test_fix_client.py source:

```
import sys
import quickfix as fix

...

class myApplication(fix.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super(fix.Application,self).__init__()
        self.session=None
        self.logon = False
    def onCreate(self, sessionID): 
        print(sessionID)
        self.session = sessionID
    def onLogon(self, sessionID):
        print("On Logon")
        self.logon = True
        self.session = sessionID
...
        
try:
        settings = fix.SessionSettings(fileName)
        application = myApplication()
        storeFactory = fix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
        logFactory = fix.FileLogFactory(settings)
        acceptor = fix.SocketAcceptor( application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory )
        print('calling acceptor.start()')
        acceptor.start()
        # while condition == true: do something
        acceptor.stop()
except (fix.ConfigError, fix.RuntimeError) as e:
    print(e)
```

test_fix_client.ini:

```
[FEED]
LOG_NAME=.\logs\fix_client.log

[SESSION]
SenderCompID=CLIENT1
TargetCompID=EXECUTOR
DataDictionary=.\FIX42.xml

[DEFAULT]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=1234
SocketReuseAddress=Y
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
FileStorePath=.\store
FileLogPath=.\logs
```

Comment: You seem to know that `NotImplementedError`  could really be a `TypeError` from the SWIG wrapper. My first suggestion is to try leaving out the `logFactory` parameter so as to reduce the problem from four to three items.

Comment: Another suggestion is to try using the included QuickFix `NullApplication` instead of deriving your own, in case the problem is in that argument.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I would have never thought of the NullApplication. It wasn't the parameters or SWIG, it was the overriding of the __init__() in my fix.Application class provoking the error. I am not sure why that is. This used to work in Python 2.7.